# update all elements in sub array based on _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this data in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae088"),
    "categoryName" : "Cat 1",
     "media" : {
        "logo" : "images (1).jpg",
        "pictures" : [ 
            {
                "file_name" : "Plr9_GA26JcA.png",
                "status" : false
            }, 
            {
                "file_name" : "images (1).jpg",
                "status" : false
            }, 
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae089"),
    "categoryName" : "Cat 2",
     "media" : {
        "logo" : "images (1).jpg",
        "pictures" : [ 
            {
                "file_name" : "Plr9_GA26JcA.png",
                "status" : false
            }, 
            {
                "file_name" : "images (1).jpg",
                "status" : false
            }, 
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to update each picture   status to false for id  `ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae088")`

Like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae088"),
    "categoryName" : "Cat 1",
     "media" : {
        "logo" : "images (1).jpg",
        "pictures" : [ 
            {
                "file_name" : "Plr9_GA26JcA.png",
                "status" : true
            }, 
            {
                "file_name" : "images (1).jpg",
                "status" : true
            }, 
        ]
    }
}
```

I have already tried with the following

```
db.services.update(

    // Criteria
    {
        '_id' : ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae088"),
    },

    // Updates
    {
        $set : {
            'media.pictures.$.status': true
        }
    }
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [positional all operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) for that:

```
db.collection.update({ _id: ObjectId("505fd43fdbed3dd93f0ae088") }, { $set: { "media.pictures.$[].status": true } })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NzbEOuDaGDe)